# How to match this expression with regex

Tags: python, regex, match

How can I match lines like the following:

```
143abd
559asd
931dgd
```

These lines will always have three numbers then three letters

I am trying to write this regex in Python. So far, I have tried the following:

```
\b0-9a-z\b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following regex will work for you:

```
import re
re.findall("^[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$", yourString)
```

Comment: @Noob it's not the right thing to edit the answerer's post where the other answer says the same.

Comment: Since you said  `i have tried "\b0-9a-z\b"`, we assume that you have the actual code and looking for the exact regular expression.

Comment: for multiline input , he must need to enable multiline modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You must need to put start and end anchors otherwise it would do a partial match.

```
^\d{3}[a-z]{3}$
```

If you want to allow both upper and lowercase letters then change your regex like below.

```
^\d{3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$
```

Code:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """143abd
... 559asd
... 931dgd
... 8765dgb"""
>>> for i in re.findall(r'(?m)^\d{3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$', s):
...     print(i)
... 
143abd
559asd
931dgd
```

Answer (score 0):

The above string would be a match to `^\d{3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$` you can write and verify your own regular expressions [here](http://regexpal.com/). When ever I need a regular expression I compile and check it there.

Comment: NOte that `\w` matches letters or digits or underscore.